# Passing value from a js to another html page and rendering it there

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to programming and I have this problem.

I have a html file, in which there is a `textbox` and `button`. When the user clicks the button I perform some operation based on the value i get from `textbox` in my `js` file.

I wish I could send the computed value ( from my `js` ) to another html file and render them.

Both the html files are present in a same directory.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cookie or query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're limited to client-side processing only, then 2 option you have include:

1) using `cookies` to store the form data

2) pass the form data as `query string` to another html page.

You would then need to extract the invidual parameters from the query string in the second html page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the information on the client's machine, which will be available for the whole site, look into cookies.

If you want to store a lot of client side data, and are sure the client is using a modern browser, look into local storage.

If you want to store the variable on the server, which will be available to multiple users, but require server side scripting, look into sessions, and ajax.